# Python: Trouble with loops and ranges

Tags: python, loops, time, range, pygame

I'm a novice programming a game in the python language using pygame. It's a cursor based game where you use your mouse. Objects are falling from the top of the screen and the objective is to catch them. I use the range function to determine how many objects will fall. I do have 2 issues with my code which I would like to get some help with. I will post the code here:

```
time = 150
level = 1
score = 0

class Bomb(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = load_image("Bomb.png")
    screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

def bomb_spawn(self):
    self.rect.x = random.randrange(640)
    self.rect.y = random.randrange(-200, -0) # Respawns at the top

def update(self):    
    if self.rect.y > 805: # Respawns if colliding with bottom screen
        self.bomb_spawn()
    if self.rect.x < 105: # I do have a border/margin so if the object spawns outside 
        self.bomb_spawn() # It will respawn
    if level == 1:
        self.rect.y += 3 # The falling speed of the object increases for each level
    elif level == 2:
        self.rect.y += 4
    elif level == 3:
        self.rect.y += 5
    elif level == 4:
        self.rect.y += 6
    elif level == 5:
        self.rect.y += 7
    elif level == 6:
        self.rect.y += 8
    elif level == 7:
        self.rect.y += 9
    else:
        self.rect.y += 10
    if time <= 1: # Game over
        self.kill()

class Clocks(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = load_image("Clock.png")
    screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

def clock_spawn(self):
    self.rect.x = random.randrange(640)
    self.rect.y = random.randrange(-200, -0)

def update(self):    
    if time < 100 and time >= 0: # Required for my current Clock range function    
        if self.rect.y > 805:
            self.clock_spawn()
    if self.rect.x < 105:
        self.clock_spawn()
    if level == 1:
        self.rect.y += 3
    elif level == 2:
        self.rect.y += 4
    elif level == 3:
        self.rect.y += 5
    elif level == 4:
        self.rect.y += 6
    elif level == 5:
        self.rect.y += 7
    elif level == 6:
        self.rect.y += 8
    elif level == 7:
        self.rect.y += 9
    else:
        self.rect.y += 10
    if time <= 1:
        self.kill()

while done == False:
time -= 0.150 # timer

level = int(score/2000) + 1 # new level when you reach 2000 points.
```

Now I will get to the point, I have some trouble with range and looping.
First off the Clock, I want the clock to spawn only if the timer is below 100.
I have managed to do this but I have one problem left. For the moment I use clock.rect.x = 2000 and the same for rect.y, This means they spawn outside my screen. I want the sprite gone / removed / killed and then it respawns when the timer is below 100. I have tried pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill and such commands however that didn't seem to work.

```
for i in range(1):

clocks = Clocks()

if time > 100:

    clocks.rect.x = 2000 # spawns outside my screen, I want to change this.
    clocks.rect.y = 2000

elif time < 100:
    clocks.rect.x = random.randrange(640)
    clocks.rect.y = random.randrange(-200, -20)

ClockGroup.add(clocks)
```

Next I do have a problem with my Bomb range. I want to increase the amount of the range for each new level. Example: in level 1 it will be 1 bomb, in level 2 there will be 2 bombs and etc.

```
for i in range(1):
bomb = Bomb()

bomb.rect.x = random.randrange(640)
bomb.rect.y = random.randrange(-200, -20)

BombGroup.add(bomb)

#I have tried some methods but none of them were working.
#Here is what I went with 
if level == 2: # This is where I am at, I don't know how to proceed.
```

Link to full code:
http://pastebin.com/cpQwi2fR
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Sincerely HJ.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have `n` bombs at level `n` try this:

```
for _ in range(level): #level goes here
    bomb = Bomb()
    bomb.rect.x = random.randrange(640)
    bomb.rect.y = random.randrange(-200, -20)
    BombGroup.add(bomb)
```

Also this snippet:

```
if level == 1:
    self.rect.y += 3 # The falling speed of the object increases for each level
elif level == 2:
    self.rect.y += 4
elif level == 3:
    self.rect.y += 5
elif level == 4:
    self.rect.y += 6
elif level == 5:
    self.rect.y += 7
elif level == 6:
    self.rect.y += 8
elif level == 7:
    self.rect.y += 9
else:
    self.rect.y += 10
```

is the same as this snippet:

```
self.rect.y += (level + 2) if level < 8 else 10
```

Now with your sprite problem, I can't help you, as I have never used pygame.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to edit the bomb range with (level). That sadly didn't work, I still get one bomb on level 1 but when it increases nothing happens. Thanks for the falling speed advice! I will use that. Sincerely HJ.

Comment: @user2977298 About the bomb issue: I do not know how `Bomb` is implemented, how `BombGroup` is implemented and how both interact with your game. My code generates `level`-times a bomb-object at random coordinates and then adds it to the bomb group.